# Get the list of all subscribers to a public graphql subscription

Tags: node.js, graphql, subscription

I'm implementing a graphql server, it must have a public subscription for public updates.
My question is, how would one get the subscriber count? Is there something I'm missing about graphql subscriptions? Are graphql endpoints even supposed to be freely available?

Comment: pub/sub or other subscription server (apollo is the transport/channel only) implementation is your job ... querying current subscription server state, too

Comment: @xadm , can you point me to an example. I wasnt able to find anything on the graphql docs

Comment: search for tutorials or on github issues

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do.  Wouldn't you already know how many subscribers, because don't you have to designate something to be a sub?

Comment: even if you create the subscription schema, you're supposed to implement it anyway, you're supposed to implement the subscriber counter there.

Comment: @AdamG. does this link help you? https://lighthouse-php.com/3.1/extensions/subscriptions.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a Publisher/Subscriber instance. Check out [this example](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions#getting-started-with-your-first-subscription).
From there you should be able to implement the counter. So each time you add a subscriber you can increment the count.

This example might also be helpful to you: https://graphql.org/blog/subscriptions-in-graphql-and-relay/

Answer (score 0):

Very useful links for you, please follow instructions from the first link to practice pub/sub and the second link is the recommendations for production.

1. https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/subscriptions
2. https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions#pubsub-implementations